Is adding a dedicated section for videos on the website good for SEO?
I have a video section on the website that includes all the videos that the company produces. We did it for the following:

Increase the media presence to rank for videos.
Rank for more keywords.
Make a library on our website.

After 2 years I found that there is no major impact from it. Do you think it's better to keep it, optimize it, or remove it?

Based on my experience having only one page with all the videos it make the page load slower, and that's not positive. Loading time matters! Here is a sample I did so you know what exactly I mean.
If I have this case, I will create a blog post with transcripts for each video.This will give you topical authority for your industry for sure.
Here is a blog I wrote for Dental SEO Pricing (Sample)
Just make sure the video is always above the fold on mobile, so you don't get Google Search Console warning about the posts.
Once you have a list of blog post links, then you can create a library with a complete list of links, or maybe added on your home page if you feel are important and relevant for your industry.
It will be beneficial for your SEO efforts and you will be ranking and covering more topics and keywords naturally.

Videos are definitely beneficial, but there are nuances.
Videos can engage users more effectively than text alone, making visitors spend more time on your site. This increased dwell time signals to search engines that your content is valuable and relevant, which can positively impact your rankings. As we recently learned from leaked Google documents, user behavior metrics indeed influence rankings, making this aspect particularly important.
Additionally, videos can be optimized with relevant keywords in their html meta-data, providing extra opportunities for ranking in search results. This can improve your site's visibility in both regular and video search results. By offering diverse content formats, you cater to different user preferences, potentially reducing bounce rates and increasing overall engagement.
Moreover, placing videos on your site can enhance content diversity, which is favored by search engines. As we know, Google's algorithms consider various content types when determining the quality and relevance of a page.

It's important to note that videos can also slow down your site's loading speed, which can EXTREMELY negatively affect SEO. To address this potential issue, be sure to implement lazy loading for your videos. This ensures that videos load only when they enter the viewport, rather than all at once when the page loads.
And ABSOLUTELY add structured data for videos to maximize their SEO value. Structured data helps search engines more accurately interpret your video's content and display it correctly in search results. Google's official documentation provides detailed guidelines on implementing structured data for videos: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/video

Of course, optimize your videos to boost user interaction and increase time on site. Use Structured Data with Schema.org’s VideoObject type to help search engines understand your content better, including video URL, thumbnails, duration, and description. High-quality thumbnails can improve click-through rates, while subtitles and transcripts aid SEO by providing indexable text. Lastly, use video compression and asynchronous loading to avoid slowing page load times and continuously monitor video effectiveness on SEO and user engagement.

Keep it, but have a strategy
Google changed how video results work in search. See this answer I wrote that details how video thumbnails are now handled.
Essentially, organic results that are mostly text content with supplemental videos no longer show the relevant videos next to them in the result previews unless the video is the main content of the page.
So, you can use this to your advantage with a videos section on your site. On your video pages, include short-form content that internally links to longer-form content related to the videos. Combined with a semantically optimized taxonomy (around topics) you could build a highly relevant knowledge hub for your niche.
With two forms of content about the same topic that cater to different forms of intent, you also increase your chances of ranking two pages on one SERP. I recently showed a client of mine whom I helped implement something similar a SERP where we've got a video page showing in the AI overview and then a long form article ranking in the top 3 organic results.
